# Setup a basic search in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

(I'm only asking here because I can't find a clear resource on this.)

I have a basic ruby on rails application: add-edit-delete as I'm learning Rails. Its hosted by heroku which is part of the question. ( http://smt-books.herokuapp.com/ )

I would like to be able to search the database which is SQLite in Development but Postgresql on heroku.

Is there any way I can do this? I have been referring to here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_search but would have no idea where to start!

Sorry if this is too broad but I wouldn't know where to start. It only needs to be a text search, nothing too complex.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're able to keep your queries in rails format (not direct SQL injection), you shouldn't have to worry about which database you're using (see the active record guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).  If you have a more complex query, you should check the SQL to see if it is compatible between Postgresql and SQLite.  If it's not, then you will have to get a bit more creative in how you set things up.  If you have specific examples, that might be more helpful in giving a more specific answer.

Comment: I suppose for a specific example it would be searching a 'title' or some text in the 'description'. Nothing else just simple searching.